# Css transition not fully animating when element is unhovered quickly

Tags: html, css, transition

From my understanding, this is a very straight forward transition, but when I open it in Chrome, the transition does not work consistently. Allowing the transition to complete in a single direction and quickly changing the state seems to break the transition.

CSS:

```
.carousel-controlls{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2000ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 2000ms ease;
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease;
}
.carousel-controlls:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-controlls">
    <a class="left" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <button class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></button>
    </a>
    <a class="right" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <button class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. Maybe it's the `height: 100%` that confuses you about when you actually hover the div? Try removing it and see if it helps.

Comment: The purpose of the height is to make the div as tall as its parent. I can see the size in the chrome dev tools so I know when I am hovering, in addition to clearly seeing when the animation starts. It seems to work on JS fiddle though, so I guess its just a bad interaction with something else.